# Uncommitable transaction prevents error logging in nested transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, try-catch, raiserror

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx), you can have a state in the catch block where you can't do any write operations unless you rollback first.

This is an issue when you're attempting to handle nested transactions and do error logging. In the following example, the exception in the nested procedure gets lost and nothing is logged.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ErrorLog', N'U') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE dbo.ErrorLog;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ErrorLog (Error NVARCHAR(4000));
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Caller') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP PROC #Caller;
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #Caller 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET XACT_ABORT ON;

  DECLARE @transCount TINYINT = @@TRANCOUNT,
          @returnCode INT,
          @errorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),
          @errorNumber INT;

  BEGIN TRY

    IF (@transCount = 0)
    BEGIN
      BEGIN TRAN;
    END;

    EXEC @returnCode = #Called;

    IF (@returnCode <> 0)
    BEGIN 
      RAISERROR(N'Error in Called. Caller returned an error', 16, -1); 
    END;

    IF (@transCount = 0)
    BEGIN
      COMMIT TRAN;
    END;


  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

    IF ((@transCount = 0) AND (XACT_STATE() <> 0))
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END;

    SELECT @errorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
           @errorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();

    INSERT dbo.ErrorLog(Error) VALUES(@errorMessage); --only this logging happens

    RAISERROR(N'Error in Caller.', 16, -1); 

    RETURN @errorNumber;

  END CATCH;

  RETURN;

END;
GO


IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Called') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP PROC #Called;
END;
GO

CREATE PROC #Called 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET XACT_ABORT ON;

  DECLARE @transCount TINYINT = @@TRANCOUNT,
          @errorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),
          @errorNumber INT;

  BEGIN TRY

    IF (@transCount = 0) --doesn't start tran, already in one
    BEGIN
      BEGIN TRAN;
    END;

    SELECT 1/0; --generate an error; this exception gets lost

    IF (@transCount = 0)
    BEGIN
      COMMIT TRAN;
    END; 

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH 

    IF ((@transCount = 0) AND (XACT_STATE() <> 0)) --cannot rollback here because this didn't start the transaction
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END;

    SELECT @errorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
           @errorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();

    INSERT dbo.ErrorLog(Error) VALUES(@errorMessage); --doesn't happen because of uncommitable transaction; raises exception, caught in CATCH block of Caller 

    RAISERROR(N'Error in Called.', 16, -1); --this doesn't happen

    RETURN @errorNumber; --nothing returned

  END CATCH;

  RETURN;
END
GO


EXEC dbo.#Caller;
GO 

SELECT * FROM dbo.ErrorLog;
GO
```

The single error logged is just the uncommitable transaction exception. Is there any way to handle nested transactions, in a TRY..CATCH, and still log errors that actually occur?

Comment: The only way I know is to use table variables since those aren't affected by rollback, but it might get really messy if your logic is complex.

Comment: Not sure that would work hey. The error log should be a persisted table. Table variable would get cleaned up after execution. I also think a table variable insert wouldn't work here too since it is a write operation, and those are not allowed in an uncommitable state.

Comment: The writing into the table variable would have to be outside the catch, or at least I assumed that, and the writing from the table variable to the errorlog table after the final rollback. Surviving the procedure boundaries would probably then need temp. tables or something else to carry the data around. Of course if the error is just one row, output parameters should work.

Comment: What I did, and it seemed to help, is wrap my error logging inside CATCH in Called in a TRY..CATCH. If the logging fails, I simply pass on the original exception via. a RAISERROR to the Caller procedure which does the logging.

Answer (score 0):

This approach helped me accomplish what I needed. Basically, in the case of a doomed tran (XACT_STATE() = -1), the entire transaction is rolled back to allow error logging at both levels while raising just one exception at the end of execution.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ErrorLog', N'U') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE dbo.ErrorLog;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ErrorLog (Error NVARCHAR(4000));
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Caller') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP PROC #Caller;
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #Caller 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET XACT_ABORT ON;

  DECLARE @transCount TINYINT = @@TRANCOUNT,
          @returnCode INT,
          @errorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),
          @errorNumber INT;

  BEGIN TRY

    IF (@transCount = 0)
    BEGIN
      BEGIN TRAN;
    END;

    EXEC @returnCode = #Called;

    IF (@returnCode <> 0)
    BEGIN 
      RAISERROR(N'Error in Called. Caller returned an error', 16, -1); 
    END;

    IF (@transCount = 0)
    BEGIN
      COMMIT TRAN;
    END;


  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

    IF (((@transCount = 0) AND (XACT_STATE() <> 0)) OR (XACT_STATE() = -1))
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END;

    SELECT @errorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
           @errorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();

    INSERT dbo.ErrorLog(Error) VALUES(@errorMessage); --only this logging happens

    RAISERROR(N'Error in Caller.', 16, -1); 

    RETURN @errorNumber;

  END CATCH;

  RETURN;

END;
GO


IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Called') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP PROC #Called;
END;
GO

CREATE PROC #Called 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET XACT_ABORT ON;

  DECLARE @transCount TINYINT = @@TRANCOUNT,
          @errorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),
          @errorNumber INT;

  BEGIN TRY

    IF (@transCount = 0) --doesn't start tran, already in one
    BEGIN
      BEGIN TRAN;
    END;

    SELECT 1/0; --generate an error; this exception gets lost

    IF (@transCount = 0)
    BEGIN
      COMMIT TRAN;
    END; 

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH 

    IF (((@transCount = 0) AND (XACT_STATE() <> 0)) OR (XACT_STATE() = -1)) --rollback even though didn't start this tran because its doomed
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END;

    SELECT @errorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
           @errorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();

    INSERT dbo.ErrorLog(Error) VALUES(@errorMessage); --doesn't happen because of uncommitable transaction; raises exception, caught in CATCH block of Caller 

    RAISERROR(N'Error in Called.', 16, -1); --this doesn't happen

    RETURN @errorNumber; --nothing returned

  END CATCH;

  RETURN;
END
GO


DECLARE @returnCode INT;
EXEC @returnCode = dbo.#Caller; --one exception raised
SELECT @returnCode AS 'returnCode'; --error code 50000 returned

SELECT * FROM dbo.ErrorLog; --both errors logged incl original exception
```